# How can I tell the difference between an Excel Template opened to edit the Template, and a Template opened via File New

Tags: excel, vba, templates

I would like to run a function when an xltm template is opened via File New, which will prompt for a file name and save as xlsm (because there are other macros I still need to run in the file)

But if I do that the function runs when I am opening the template to edit it.  How can I tell the difference ?